# PHP - Auto-submit forms in PHP using onchange

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, upload

I am trying to create a form where when the user chooses a file, the file chosen will automatically upload to the database by going to the action in form. I used the `onchange` function and it just sends me to my php file in which that file contains my uploading system. What i think my problem is about my `$_POST['asdasd']`, but i cant really think of any other solutions to this.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="includes/profile_picture_inc.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="upload" onchange="document.getElementById('form').submit();">
</form>
```

The PHP File:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $target_dir = "../users/".$_SESSION['u_id']."/image/";
    $str = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    $rand = substr(str_shuffle($str), 0, 10);
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = $rand . '.' . end($temp);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $newfilename;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ". <br/>";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image. <br/>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists. <br/>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large. <br/>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed. <br/>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded. <br/>";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            require 'database_inc.php';
            $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_profile` = '$newfilename' WHERE 1";
            if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
                $_SESSION['profile_picture'] = $newfilename;
                header("Location: ../profile.php");
            } else {
                echo "The query has not been updated. <br/>";
            }

        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. <br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['submit'])` - how many buttons with the name `submit` did you click exactly in the front end to get the form to submit …?

Comment: Nothing, i changed it so that the form will automatically be sent to the database, but i really dont know what i will put to the `isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: Where is `$_POST['asdasd']` I cant see it?

Comment: its just an example

Comment: This was used to check if a value for the submit button was found inside the POST parameters - to determine whether the form was actually submitted, or if this is just the first _GET_ request, in which case only the form needs to be displayed. Now you don’t have a submit button any more, so you need to make that decision based on something else. Either check for another value (the `file` field won’t come in $_POST though), or simply check the request method via the $_SERVER array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not saving because in the php file you have the line

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

add in the form a hidden field

```
<form action="includes/profile_picture_inc.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="upload" onchange="document.getElementById('form').submit();">
   <input type="hidden" name="submited" value="1" />
</form>
```

And in php change the line

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['submited'])) {
```

That should do it

Comment: it doesnt do anything

Comment: @MatthewBustarde What do you mesn? Blank page? error? what? doesn't submit?

Comment: it doesnt submit

Comment: @MatthewBustarde I edited the answer Note the hidden fields name in the form also!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the $_POST['submit'] validation, try to check if the request is a $_POST.

To do that you can use something like

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') { … }
```

or

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {…}
```

i recommend you to use the first one.

PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php